# Determine a continous function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all n $c_n \leq \int_{1/n}^1 f(x) dx \leq b_n$

Tags: analysis, summation

Define the sequences
$$
a_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{j}{n}} \ \text{for} \ n = 2,3,4 ...
$$
$$
b_n = \sum_{j=2}^n \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{j}{n}} \ \text{for} \ n = 2,3,4 ...
$$
$$
c_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{j}{n}} \ \text{for} \ n = 2,3,4 ...
$$
In an eanrlier question I have argued for that $a_n \geq b_n$ for $n=2,3,4..$ as
$$
a_n = \sum_{j=2}^n \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{j}{n}} + \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} = b_n + \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
Furthermore that $b_n \geq c_n$ as
$$
b_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
which means that
$$
b_n + \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} = c_n + \frac{1}{n}
$$
but as $\frac{1}{n} \geq \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$for $n=2,3,4..$ this means that $b_n \geq c_n$ which I hope you can clarify as well.

I think I have to use this to find the function $f$ but I really have no idea how to start. Can you help me?

Comment: see here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/i=sum+1%2Fn*sqrt%28k%2Fn%29+at+k%3D2+to+k%3Dn and here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fn*sqrt%28k%2Fn%29+at+k%3D1+to+k%3Dn-1 it's related to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html

Comment: How can I use the harmonic series to find $f$?

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives the relation between the Harmonic series and the hurwitz zeta function makes the difference between $b_n$ and $c_n$ and use the integral in the this link https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HurwitzZetaFunction.html